# Mesos tasks use more resources than specified

Tags: mesos

I tried to launch a framework that has 1000 tasks, on a Mesos cluster with 208 cores. In scheduler, I specify that each task requires 2 cores. But some tasks just failed with error message: `Task uses more resources cpus(*):4; mem(*):4096; disk(*):4096 than available cpus(*):2; mem(*):2048; disk(*):2048`.  I also try to monitor the resource usage dynamically on the cluster.  And I noticed that each task actually consume 4 cores based on the information

```
2016/11/02 02:25:10.073 mesos_scheduler INFO 208.0 cpu 98.0 used, 807768.0 memory 100352.0 used, 44052112.0 disk 100352.0 used, 24.0 active tasks
2016/11/02 02:25:10.574 mesos_scheduler INFO 208.0 cpu 96.0 used, 807768.0 memory 98304.0 used, 44052112.0 disk 98304.0 used, 24.0 active tasks
2016/11/02 02:25:15.301 mesos_scheduler INFO 208.0 cpu 94.0 used, 807768.0 memory 96256.0 used, 44052112.0 disk 96256.0 used, 23.0 active tasks
2016/11/02 02:25:15.803 mesos_scheduler INFO 208.0 cpu 92.0 used, 807768.0 memory 94208.0 used, 44052112.0 disk 94208.0 used, 23.0 active tasks
2016/11/02 02:25:16.728 mesos_scheduler INFO 208.0 cpu 90.0 used, 807768.0 memory 92160.0 used, 44052112.0 disk 92160.0 used, 22.0 active tasks
2016/11/02 02:25:17.229 mesos_scheduler INFO 208.0 cpu 88.0 used, 807768.0 memory 90112.0 used, 44052112.0 disk 90112.0 used, 22.0 active tasks
```

The code I wrote to specify the number of cores are as follows

```
 cpus = executor.resources.add()
 cpus.name = "cpus"
 cpus.type = mesos_pb2.Value.SCALAR
 cpus.scalar.value =2
```

Do I use the api correctly?

Comment: What version of Mesos? What scheduler are you using? Can you provide minimal working copy of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you've assigned 2 CPUs to the `executor` and 2 CPUs to the `task`, resulting in a total of 4.

In Mesos, every `task` runs under an `executor`.  When you do not specify an `executor`, Mesos uses a very light-weight default executor that occupies 0.01 CPU and 32 MB of memory.